# discord.js v13 Cannot send a message to all the members in the same vc (except bots and the host)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I am trying to make a similar game as the known game Mafia/werewolf and I only need the bot to send a specific text (mafia) to a specific number of users in the VC and the rest I want them to get the same message (good). However, I don't want the (killers) to receive the (good) message again.

```js
client.on("message", (msg) => {
    if (msg.content.startsWith(prefix + "Game")) {
        if (!msg.channel.guild) return;

        let channel = msg.member.voiceChannel;

        let toCheck = channel.members;
        let random1 = toCheck.random();
        let randomE = toCheck.random();

        random1.send("killer");
        msg.channel.send(`${random1} killer`);

        randomE.send("good");
        msg.channel.send(`${randomE} good`);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want killer not to receive messages you can try `filter`

**Ex:**

```js
data = [{
    "team": "good",
    "id": "player_1"
  },
  {
    "team": "evil",
    "id": "player_2"
  },
  {
    "team": "good",
    "id": "player_3"
  },
  {
    "team": "good",
    "id": "player_4"
  },
  {
    "team": "evil",
    "id": "player_5"
  }
]

var result = data.filter(obj => {
  return obj.team === 'evil'
})

console.log(result)
```

And result

```json
[
{
"team": "evil",
"id": "player_2"
},
{
"team": "evil",
"id": "player_5"
}
]
```

Use **for** to send message

**Ex:**

```js
for (let item of result) {
console.log(`*player: ${item.id}\n*team: ${item.team}`)
}

/* tada

*player: player_2
*team: evil
*player: player_5
*team: evil
*/
```